# How do I track Elastic Beanstalk application deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have several Elastic Beanstalk environments and new application versions are deployed to each up to several times a day. I would like to track who deployed an app version to an environment (**who**, **what version**, **which environment**). EB offers a notification, but it only contains the environment info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also puzzled with this and consulted with Amazon support in that regards. The suggested approach is to enable [CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudtrail.html) logs and find the deployment event there. This log contains the source IP, user agent, time of request and the action taken.